# Does $\int_1^\infty x^{-x}$ converges?

Tags: improper-integrals

I want to use the comparison test - I thought of $1 \over x$. but this function is larger and also diverges so it doesn't help me much.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your basic instincts are off. Use a calculator to calculate $x^{-x}$ for some values < 10 to get a correct understanding how your integrand behaves. Then take a look at the solution (better: hint) below.

Comment: L'Hospital's rule does *not* show that it tends to $\infty$, since $x\ln x\to\infty$ (note that $\ln x/(1/x)$ is $\infty/0$, so you cannot use L'Hospital here).

Comment: You're right I edited easier than I thought Thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 1):

If $x>2$ hen
$$
\frac{1}{x^x}<\frac{1}{x^2}.
$$